# build docker image from local (unpublished) image

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have two Dockerfiles:

```
mydockerfiles
|_baseimage
|_myapp
```

Now I run `docker build -t munchkin/base -f baseimage .`
Now I want to use this image as `FROM` within my `myapp`-Dockerfile:

```
FROM munchkin/base
```

But when I run `docker build -t munchkin/myapp -f myapp .` I get:

```
Pulling repository docker.io/munchkin/base
Error: image munchkin/base not found
```

I believe it could be possible if I publish my first image on dockerhub - but is it also possible without publishing - just use the local image?

Edit:
or, as alternative, is it possible without even building my first image? Just do something like a script include?

Comment: I can't reproduce this error. Please can you post the output of `docker version` and `docker info` please?

Comment: @JHarris: techtabu already found the solution

Comment: Munchkin thanks, but my point was that this _isn't_ an error on my machine. So I'd like to know what versions you're using to potentially help others.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you have to specify the version explicitly. When I did, I was able to build. When I did not, I got the same error.

```
docker build -t munchkin/base:latest -f baseimage .
```

And then you can use this images.

Comment: Thank you! Stupid mistake =/

Comment: thanks for making this mistake so I didn't have to.